# Can I call a generic function using function.call()?

Tags: generics, typescript, call

usually generic functions are defined and called like so:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
const id1 = identity<string>("hei");
```

Is there a way to call generic functions with `function.bind()`, `function.call()`, or `function.apply()`? How do I specify the type arguments?

This, for example, is compiled correctly, but the compiler gives me an error.

```
function boundIdentity<T>(this: T): T {
    return this;
}
const id2 = boundIdentity.call<Object>({});
```

If I remove the type argument, the function works as expected, but I don't get type inference on `id2`.

[See in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20identity%3CT%3E(arg%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arg%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20id1%20%3D%20identity%3Cstring%3E(%22hei%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20boundIdentity%3CT%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20id2%20%3D%20boundIdentity.call%3CObject%3E(%7B%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You can create an interface that describes what you want like this:

```
interface IBoundIdentityFunction {
    <T>(this: T): T;
    call<T>(this: Function, ...argArray: any[]): T;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let boundIdentity: IBoundIdentityFunction = function<T>(this: T): T {
    return this;
}
```

And now you will get type inference when you do this:

```
const id2 = boundIdentity.call<Object>({});
```

[See in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IBoundIdentityFunction%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20call%3CT%3E(this%3A%20Function%2C%20...argArray%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20boundIdentity%3A%20IBoundIdentityFunction%20%3D%20function%3CT%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20id2%20%3D%20boundIdentity.call%3CObject%3E(%7B%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 1):

Now this can be done with instantiation expressions.

```
const boundIdentityWithType = boundIdentity<Object>;
const id2 = boundIdentity.call({});
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKAQwCcBzALkXwEpb9EBvAWAChFvFy0oQ5JBUoBuTgF9OEBAGcoyFAEZEAXkUYseeeRhhKJAEQALNDEP1xHTqEiwEiAEZxwKAJLpMMHARJRjMLJMjHSsnDy8-IJI-oFWUtYcMmDyTi5g7p5aAOrexgDiGGi6EGpprh6a3ngA8o4AVmjQhFbJqagATGXOFVnVuf6FYMUwEAB0EKQANlPELBKWnAD0SxEAegD8QA)