# TypeScript: Why is this return value unknown when the callback function is typed?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to type this `fmap` function I have. Here's my latest attempt:

```js
export const __skip__ = Symbol('skip');

type ReduceFn<T> = Array<T>['reduce']

/**
 * Filter-map. Like map, but you may omit entries by returning `__skip__`.
 */
export function fmap<TVal,TReturn>(this:TVal[], callback: (this: TVal[], ...args:[currentValue: TVal, index: number])=>TReturn|typeof __skip__): TReturn[] {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, (accum: TReturn[], ...args) => {
        let x = callback.call(this, ...args);
        if (x !== __skip__) {
            accum.push(x);
        }
        return accum;
    }, []);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wPodQawJZhZwC8cAygJ4C2ARhADYAUA5LgcwJQDcAUDzBTDA4AJWAATAK4JgAMWQAeACoA+EnACCUKAEMKylQG1mUCdODMAunwD0AKjs84duLLz0YwKAFoqOsAB0cAAyeDjCfmAANHA0kvAUEJJwfhRwEFR48MDIMFB4wKixaaYwklDIeMgA5nAABlhshBh1AU52NjygkLBwAGaSyAgweCj9kcoAajr0UUpiZRUqjDAAFnioAFxK0-SGljEIM-Q0Ogg4m3Ar61twOzP7MQHPOlDVW4YI5aa5u5LAl3uszgVXEoEuyEktC8lg4xBU82Ai2QAB8BEIIH04I18M0OICFuVkPs4ABvJxwSmlImabR6AJgKAQGDMwTAAKmKQyAJHehMNYbGKMM5fKgEpFEx5wZ4BV7vDgkNTkykqlX0JFwEDqXknM44HnHa6C6UvN6obgU1WUvBYxhagCExFIOIIWAVyqtnpFUIZklQqztFs9lIAvpardSKnBvVReKqQzF9haw0A)

It's saying `x` is `unknown`

[image]

Even though it knows what `callback` returns:

[image]

How come? How do I fix the errors?

N.B. I typed `args` as `[currentValue: TVal, index: number]` to try to simplify a bit, but I think it should be `Parameters<ReduceFn<TVal>>`

---

Also, I know the signature is a bit funny. The usage of `this` is intentional for legacy reasons.

Here's an example usage:

```
const keys = fmap.call(feeIds, id => feeIdToKey[id] || __skip__)
```

Comment: It seems to work better if you replace `Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, ...)` with `this.reduce(...)` and still better if you replace the `...args` with an explicit list of args (since there is a 4th argument to the reduce callback, namely the array itself). However, those don't make the type inference in `fmap.call(feeIds, ...)` work correctly. To get the `call` working you may need this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559086/can-i-call-a-generic-function-using-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the method `Array.prototype.reduce.call` is trying to infer the type automatically based on the generic type of `Array`, but is unable to infer it properly since the default generic type of `Array` is `any` (that is `Array<any>`). But you can pass in whichever generic type you want to the method `call`, manually, rather than relying on the automatic inference in this specific instance.

Here's how you can do it:

```
export function fmap<TVal, TReturn>(this: TVal[], callback: (this: TVal[], ...args: [currentValue: TVal, index: number, array: TVal[]]) => TReturn | typeof __skip__): TReturn[] {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call<
        // Here's our manually passed in generic type
        TVal[], [callbackfn: (previousValue: TReturn[], currentValue: TVal, currentIndex: number, array: TVal[]) => TReturn[], initialValue: TReturn[]], TReturn[]
    >(this, (accum: TReturn[], ...args) => {
        let x = callback.call(this, ...args);
        if (x !== __skip__) {
            accum.push(x);
        }
        return accum;
    }, []);
};
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvVD4W)

**NOTE**

I also had to add the parameter `array: TVal[]` to this line: `callback: (this: TVal[], ...args: [currentValue: TVal, index: number, array: TVal[]]) => TReturn | typeof __skip__`, since `Array.prototype.reduce`'s callback param expects also a fourth, `array`, parameter.

Comment: Nice! There's no way to get callers to infer the types without also typing the `fmap.call` is there? e.g. https://go.mpen.ca/4hnah

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a convenient solution in your case, because you would always have to type `fmap.call` manually. I apologize, but I am out of ideas on how to make the automatic type inference work in this specific case.

Comment: No problem, it's better than what I had before :-) I should probably fix these `.call`s anyway.